# Appending text in a HTML form textarea with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a selectlist that is populated from a CFC. Based on the what a user selects from my selectlist, a set of predefined text is written into a textarea. Currently my code will replace whatever is currently in the textarea with the CFC data. I am looking to instead append the text but cannot figure out how.

**Here is how I populate my list:**

```
$("#addDescriptionForm").submit(function(){
   // prevent native form submission here
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#addDescriptionForm').serialize(),
            url: "actionpages/add_descriptions_modal.cfm",
            beforeSend: function () {
            $("#addDescriptionResponse").html( "" );
            $('.loader').show();
            },
            complete: function () {
            $('.loader').hide(3000);
            },
            success: function() {
              PopulateSelectLists();//Call Function to refresh selectlist
              $("#addDescriptionResponse").html( "Successfully added description." );
              
              //reset modal form
              $( '#addDescriptionForm' ).each(function(){
                    this.reset();
                });
            
              }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

**When a selection is chosen, here is my javascript that replaces the text in the textarea with the data from my CFC:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#detail_ticket_lines table").on('change', ".tr_clone_lines select[id*=detail_descriptionDD]", function(event) {
        var selectelement=$(this);
        // Populate the  description textarea when the selectlist ajax completes successfully
        if ($(this).val() == 'ADD NEW') { // require a URL
          $('#addDescriptionsLink').trigger('click'); // redirect
          return false;
         }
         else
         {
            $.ajax({
                url:'cfcs/get_descriptions.cfc?method=getDetail&returnformat=json',
                    data: { description: $(selectelement).val() }
                ,
                success: function(response) {
                        $("#detail_service_detail"+$(selectelement).closest("tr").attr("data-index")).val( response );
                        console.log("Details entered into desciption field");
                    },
                error:function(msg){
                   console.log("Error with descriptions field 1 Loading");
                    }
              });
         }
    });
```

**Here is my HTML form elements:**

```
<select name="detail_descriptionDD$rowindex" id="detail_descriptionDD$rowindex">
        <option>----Choose from the list----</option>
        <option>ADD NEW</option>
        </select>

<textarea class='expanding' name="detail_service_detail$rowindex" cols="100" rows="5" id="detail_service_detail$rowindex" tabindex="0" ></textarea>
```

How can I revampt this to append the current text in my textare instead of replacing it, once an option is chosen from the selectlist?

Comment: `const element = $("#detail_service_detail"+$(selectelement).closest("tr")); const currentVal = element.attr("data-index")).val(); element.val(currentVal + response);` Explanation: Get the existing value out of the textarea first. Save it in a variable. Set the variable + response as the new value.

Comment: If I use:
var textArea = $("#detail_service_detail"+$(selectelement).closest("tr").value);       $("#detail_service_detail"+$(selectelement).closest("tr").attr("data-index")).val(  textArea + response );
it returns: [object Object] for the original conttent of the textArea.

Comment: Well yes, you're selecting `.value` as the element? All you basically have to do is copy / paste the code I gave you in the correct position.

Comment: Your code returns this error: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #detail_service_detail[object Object]

Comment: I don't fully understand how your element selection works. It seems rather confusing. But the idea is pretty simple to follow. With `.val()` you get a value. With `.val( newValue )` you set it. All you have to do is get it, put it together with new val and set it.

Comment: In our form, we can add rows by clicking a button. We then loop through the rows when adding data to our table. I'm assuming that it why the javascript cannot determine the value in the object. Can you find out the value of a textarea that the cursor is currently in instead? Something like that?

Comment: There is code missing. Where is PopulateSelectLists();?

Comment: value/val() will only work with a form input, this selector looks like it is selecting the tr and then looking for the attribute data-index `.closest("tr").attr("data-index")).val( response )` so val won't work on that, you need text(), textContent or innerHTML. As far as I can tell, could do with seeing some HTML